# Android ExoPlayer delay when playing audio

Tags: android, kotlin, media, exoplayer

In my app, I'm trying to use ExoPlayer to play audio and video together at the same time using `MergingMediaSource`.

The problem is that it buffers for several minutes, and when it starts playing the audio is really distorted, sometimes sped up for a few seconds or crackly.

I've spent hours searching for a solution and I've come up with nothing.

The player

```
val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(application)
    .setRenderersFactory(
        DefaultRenderersFactory(application)
            .setEnableAudioTrackPlaybackParams(true)
            .setEnableAudioOffload(true)
            .setExtensionRendererMode(DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_ON)
    )
    .build()
```

This is the code where I load the streams

```
val factory = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory())
val videoItem = factory.createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(streams.filterIsInstance<DomainStream.Video>().first().url))
val soundItem = factory.createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(streams.filterIsInstance<DomainStream.Audio>().first().url))
val mergedSource = MergingMediaSource(true, videoItem, soundItem)

viewModel.player.setMediaSource(mergedSource)
viewModel.player.prepare()
viewModel.player.playWhenReady = true
```

Here's a log of what happens when I start the player

```
surfaceSize [eventTime=0.10, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, 1080, 608]
timeline [eventTime=0.86, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=PLAYLIST_CHANGED
  period [?]
  window [?, seekable=false, dynamic=true]
]
mediaItem [eventTime=0.86, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, reason=PLAYLIST_CHANGED]
state [eventTime=0.86, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, BUFFERING]
playWhenReady [eventTime=0.86, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, true, USER_REQUEST]
timeline [eventTime=0.95, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=SOURCE_UPDATE
  period [?]
  window [?, seekable=false, dynamic=false]
]
loading [eventTime=0.95, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, true]
timeline [eventTime=1.21, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=SOURCE_UPDATE
  period [2048.92]
  window [2048.92, seekable=true, dynamic=false]
]
videoEnabled [eventTime=2.01, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0]
audioEnabled [eventTime=2.02, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0]
tracks [eventTime=2.02, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, []]
downstreamFormat [eventTime=2.02, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, id=1, mimeType=video/avc, codecs=avc1.640028, res=1920x1080]
videoDecoderInitialized [eventTime=2.03, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, c2.goldfish.h264.decoder]
videoInputFormat [eventTime=2.03, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, id=1, mimeType=video/avc, codecs=avc1.640028, res=1920x1080]
audioDecoderInitialized [eventTime=2.04, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, c2.android.aac.decoder]
audioInputFormat [eventTime=2.05, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, id=1, mimeType=audio/mp4a-latm, codecs=mp4a.40.5, channels=2, sample_rate=44100, language=en]
videoSize [eventTime=88.44, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, 1920, 1080]
renderedFirstFrame [eventTime=88.44, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, Surface(name=null)/@0xed8b97b]
```

EDIT: I also attempted to load just the audio using Androids built-in MediaPlayer API, and the same issue also occurred. Testing the same URL on my PC plays fine, so it couldn't be an issue with the source.